# export pandas df to SAS xpt (xport module): date converted to string

Tags: python, pandas, sas

EDIT 27/09/2021 19:20

If I change Length to :

- 1 : return D
- 2 : return 23/12/2020
- 3-8: return 04/09/2021 (expected)
- more than 9 : an error raise

I don't understand...

[image]

---

EDIT 27/09/2021 18:30

I think problem may comes from format of date that should be number of days since 1960 for SAS
So I have converted my date like this, and change format of dataset to ddmmyy10.

But now, I can open xpt file but when I want to see data, I got an error :

[image]

---

I want to produce xpt files (SAS transfert format) from Pandas dataframes but do not understand how xport.v56.dump function works.

Dataframe may contain integer, float, string and date/datetime but it seems that xpt library dataset only have Character or Numeric not Date/Datetime.

If I try to xport field with datetime, I get an error `Could not coerce column {column!r} to {dtype}`...

[image]

For example, variable #17 and #18 above should be datetime

Is it possible to define Type 'Datetime' with ddmmyy10. SAS format?

Maybe I misunderstand something with xpt files format?

Comment: Do you need to use xpt for any particular reason? It might be much easier to save it as a .sas7bdat file.

Comment: we are asked to send data in this xpt format to insert data from a database to another;

Comment: Gotcha. I haven't used Pandas to convert to xpt, but xpt certainly does support Date formats. Since it's expecting a SAS datetime, maybe the xpt converter is not directly translating the value to an actual date but rather displaying it as-is. What if you took the date and converted it directly to a SAS datetime (number of seconds since Jan 1st 1960), then formatted it as a date in Python?

Comment: I would investigate in the first case if you have a problem with invalid dates - SAS date only has certain valid range, it doesn't go on forever (I think 1642 or something).  Hopefully you don't have dates before that, but is it possible you have some values that are "wrong" (either too big or too small, or maybe you're not handling nulls correctly?)

Comment: I calculate date 2021-09-04 in days (not seconds) since 1960-01-01 and get 22527 ; it should be in seconds ? I do not have null values

Comment: I try with seconds but not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If I change Length to 7 or 8 it works but not with >=9`

This is your issue!  Length, in SAS, for numeric variables is the number of *bytes* used to store the number.  All numerics in SAS are 8 byte numerics; you can't store a numeric with more than 8 bytes.  You can use less, but shouldn't.

Length in numeric variables is not the *display width*, that is controlled in the format.  In character variables, in single byte character sets, it does overlap (they're the same, length and display width, for the most part), hence the common confusion.